# Angular: how to create a responsive dynamic menu with multiple pages reutilizing the same overlay?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular application and need to create a responsive menu, like the one of https://m3.material.io/.

[image]

Basically, it's an overlay containing some entries, and when you click on the ones with a left or right arrow, it "goes" to the previous or next page of the menu, but it's all in the same overlay.

Then if you click on an entry that has no arrows, it means that the entry reached the end of the flow, and clicking on it will route to the connected page.

I am thinking of many ways to create this but not sure which would be the correct approach.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps use the [@angular/cdk/stepper](https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a tree-like structure in your component and the current displayed level stored in a variable (starting at 0). You use your current displayed level storage variable to pass to the html the list of items to be displayed.

When an item with an arrow is clicked, you update the current displayed level going deeper. When the end is reached you navigate/do whatever the link does.

Comment: Yes, that could be an idea. But how would I handle custom elements, for example a special button that opens a modal, or fetching a list of items and show it?

Comment: Well, I would first define what my menu can and can't do, so you don't try to make something too complex. But you can (in your tree structure) have a property for each leaf that indicates the action to execute, and when the leaf is visited you use a handler function to call the corresponding service or do any action you need.